# Swagger autogenerated schema models (FastAPI, Pydantic)

Tags: python, api, swagger, fastapi, pydantic

I'm building my first project with FastAPI and I'm using Pydantic models so that I have autogenerated Swagger documentation for my API. I have an endpoint which have two Pydantic models as its input. Here's a signature:

```py
@router.post('', tags=['earnings'], response_model=List[Earnings])
async def get_earnings(
        partner: Partner = Body(...),
        filters: Optional[EarningsFilters] = Body(None)
):
    ...
```

Since there's no dedicated model which contains all the inputs for this endpoint, Swagger creates a [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeLfM.png) with a generated name `Body_get_earnings_earnings_post`.

I'm wondering is it a good practice to have such generated names in the documentation, or I'd rather have a dedicated model for each of my endpoints, for this case something like `EarningsInReqeust`?